# CSS overflow-y:scroll; works in chrome but not in edge on html tag

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, overflow, microsoft-edge

I'm working on webpage where I want to make whole page scrollable, when I add overflow-y:scroll on html tag it works perfectly in Chrome browser, but not in Edge and Firefox.

How can I fix that problem ?

This is index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
    {% block content %}
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-auto col-sm-auto col-lg-auto position-relative mx-auto">
        <h1 class="postmod">მოგესალმებით ციფრული ლიტერატურის 
    პორტალზე</h1>
    </div>


</div>

<div class="container-fluid mainnews">
    <div class="col-md-auto col-sm-auto col-lg-auto position-relative">
        <h2 class="postmod">სიახლეები</h2>
         {% for new in news %}
        <h4>{{ new.title }}</h4>
        <p>{{ new.message }}</p>
    {% endfor %}

    </div>

</div>
    {% endblock %}
```

This is master.css file

```
html {
  min-height: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at bottom, #1b2735 0%, #090a0f 100%);
  position: fixed;
  overflow:scroll;
  


}

body{

    background-color: transparent;
    color: #0d6efd;
    overflow-y:scroll;

    height: 100%;
    min-height: 0px;

}
```

Comment: Please put up enough example code in your question so we can see the problem for ourselves.

Comment: Added mate as requested

Comment: Which version of Edge are you using? I make test with your code and put some paragraphs inside '<p>' and it works well in all the browsers. There's no difference between Edge and Chrome, both can scroll well. Please provide the [code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce the issue**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_overflow-y), `overflow-y:scroll` works on Microsoft Edge.
It is tested with the same code and the text was just copied and pasted.[image: overflow-y:scroll image on Microsoft-Edge]

Comment: the error was caused by bootstrap container wrong usage thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may be using an older version of Edge and Firefox. Check this link to see what versions support overflow-y: [www3schools - overflow-y](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp)

Comment: I'm using the latest versions of both chrome and edge